# 2 routes of different view functions but same url pattern (with parameter) but Flask/ Jinja2 decided to neglect one of the view function

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have 2 routes and they are of the same url pattern - `@app.route('/<var1>/')` and `@app.route('/<var2>/')`.

And they have different view function - `view_fcn_1` and `view_fcn_2` respectively.

---

However, when I called them in my template `my-template.html` by

```
<a href="{{url_for('view_fcn_1', var1='I-am-var1') }}">First View Function</a>
<a href="{{url_for('view_fcn_2', var1='I-am-var2') }}">Second View Function</a>
```

I actually went into `view_fcn_1` when I was clicking the link for the **second view function**

I know I can *kind of* resolve the issue by making the URL pattern different, e.g. `@app.route('/<var1>/1')` and `@app.route('/<var2>/2')`.

But I wonder if this is an expected behaviour or if I have missed out anything so I end up with this funny bahaviour of my code?

Thank you so much in advanced!

---

Below shows you that I indeed went into `view_fcn_1` when I was supposedly calling `view_fcn_2`

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5020/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2020 02:28:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2020 02:28:48] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 308 -
first
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2020 02:28:48] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2020 02:28:49] "GET /I-am-var1/ HTTP/1.1first
" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2020 02:28:50] "first
GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
first
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2020 02:28:51] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
first
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2020 02:28:52] "GET /I-am-var2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
first
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2020 02:28:52] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

My app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<var1>/')
def view_fcn_1(var1):
    print('first')
    return('generated by first view function' + var1)

@app.route('/<var2>/')
def view_fcn_2(var2):
    print('second')
    return('generated by second view function' + var2)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('/my-template.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0", "5000")
```

my-template.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="{{url_for('view_fcn_1', var1='I-am-var1') }}">First View Function</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('view_fcn_2', var2='I-am-var2') }}">Second View Function</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `@app.route('/<var1>/')` and `@app.route('/<var2>/')` have the same pattern, so whichever matches first is called.

You may be able to create a [custom converter](https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html#url-converters) that suits your needs depending on what `var1` and `var2` are, but really there should be no reason why you can't just define explicit routes.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: (1/2) Thank you for telling me this is an expected behaviour. So now it seems to me that the `url_for('view_fcn_2', var2='I-am-var2')` really just return the url only, and it does not even go into the function `view_fcn_2`! So after it gets the url, i.e. localhost:5020/I-am-var2/, it will then look into my routes and call the first match.

Comment: (2/2) I guess my issue is that I didn't know how `url_for` actually work and I didn't know using variable in routes allows any arbitrary url to match with the route as long as the pattern matches. So I did a test - (running the app with the exact same code as above) I accessed localhost:5020/test/ and I was returned generated by first view functiontest. I think I missed out some basic but important part of Flask before. Now you have helped me gather the missing pieces. Thank again!!

Comment: As for what I'm trying to accomplish - (1/2) My actual view functions do more things than printing and returning a string. There're 3 different tasks I need do, so I wrote 3 view functions. The view functions take in one parameter, and the parameter is fed into the view function in this way as described `<a href="{{url_for('view_fcn_1', var1='I-am-var1') }}">First View Function</a>`

Comment: As for what I'm trying to accomplish - (2/2)There're more than 1 values (say, 20) I need to feed in the 3 view functions. I wanted to list out all the urls for my user on the `'/'` page. Because it'll be 60 routes with just 3 types of view functions, I don't really want to define explicit routes. So I decided to create just 3 routes with parameters and 3 view functions, and not defining the routes explicitly.